# Drupal link content type to panel page

Tags: path, drupal-7, panel

1 / I have a content type 'Training'

2 / Standard link: www.yoursite.com/node/5

3 / With pathauto pattern:
Pattern for all Training paths:
training/[node:nid]/[node:title] (www.yoursite.com/training/5/learning-drupal)
It is goed to have a url like this.

4 / Url should be always linked to a panel page I've made.

I think I have to skip "step 3" and find a way to automatically generate a link (as above) when a new training has been submitted ...? So it links to the panel page and not the node ID?

Suggestions?

Comment: For now, I've made a solution with rewrite rules and htaccess. Don't know if this is a correct solution, but it works for now.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/206185 cheers!!!